# What are the types of bag loot items and how much are they worth?

Tags: payday-2

Bag loot items are things like stacks of cash, gold bricks, or jewellery which you have to haul to a dropoff location in order to be rewarded for. What are the different types of these items and how much are they each worth? Does difficulty or type of mission affect their value?

Comment: Does anyone have any loot bag info for [Diamond Store](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Diamond_Store)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From some old patch notes:

> We now display mission bags value on PAYDAY for both mandatory and additional bags in TAB stats screen during gameplay.

The types are

- Cash
- Meth
- Weapons
- Gold
- Jewelry
- Coke
- Painting

There is a scaling based on difficulty and the multipliers are

- **1x** for Normal,
- **3.5x** for Hard,
- **6.25x** for Very Hard and
- **9x** for Overkill.
- *Death Wish to be added.*

These also affect contract pay with same multipliers.

---

Update 12 introduced a new mechanic where *additional* bags are more valuable than *mandatory* bags (minimum bags to complete objective).

Comment: Rewards tested in Firestarter (weapons, cash), Rats (Cash, meth) and Bank Heist: Gold (gold)

Comment: Note that coke, gold, & cash can also be found in firestarter in the evidence room of the FBI building (day 2).

Comment: @ObliviousSage Haven't tested those (yet)

Comment: I have noticed that you get more money for additional bags than you do for mandatory bags (the first 4 bags on Watchdogs are to the order of $9,000, subsequent bags are to the order of $81,000). I think this may also be the case for Jewelry Store and Diamond Store, but I'm not certain.

Comment: @Unionhawk Feel free to add to the answer, it's community wiki because it's just too much to handle by myself, and there's no point in having an answer for each few values/bags.

Comment: @3ventic I was planning on it once I had the numbers

Comment: Does anyone have any loot bag info for [Diamond Store](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Diamond_Store)?

Comment: This does not answer the question of "How much are they worth"..

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft It used to, but the bag worths changed too often for me to keep the answer up-to-date. No information > wrong information IMO. The answer was marked community wiki so people it could be kept up to date as a community, but nothing came of that.